# Concatenate two .y inputs

Tags: c

I am having two inputs :`video1.y` and `video2.y` .I want to Concatenate these two files to create one `video.y` file ??I am writing code in C .It may be basic question but not able to do that !! Both inputs are having same hight and width .
Code:

```
int main()
{
   // Open two files to be merged
   FILE *fp1 = fopen("D:\\dump\\video1.y", "rb");
   FILE *fp2 = fopen("D:\\dump\\video2.y", "rb");

   // Open file to store the result
   FILE *fp3 = fopen("D:\\dump\\video.y", "wb");
   char c;  //Change char to int as per answer given by user3710044..
            //...Which is working !!
   if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL || fp3 == NULL)
   {
         puts("Could not open files");
         exit(0);
   }

   // Copy contents of first file to video3.y
   while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
      fputc(c, fp3);

   // Copy contents of second file to video3.y
   while ((c = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)
      fputc(c, fp3);

   printf("Merged video1.y and video2.y into video.y");

   fclose(fp1);
   fclose(fp2);
   fclose(fp3);
   return 0;
}
```

video1.y and video2.y are of 55 MB .and my output is 3 KB.I am not able to concatenate this two inputs

Comment: If you just want to concatenate the two inputs then use dos command to append binary files, use the COPY command with the /b switch.                   The syntax is as follows:
`copy <source1> /b + <source2> /b [....] <targetfile>`
-or-
`copy /b <source1> + <source2> [....] <targetfile>`

Comment: Thanks Ashwin for your answer .My aim is to just concatenate the two inputs .I have written c program for the same which is having some logical error so thats i can not concatenate this inputs into output video .BUt your answer helped me a lot .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the `c` variable is a `char` this cannot hold the value for `EOF` and all 256 byte values.

As it happens on your machine `char` is a signed type so the cast return result from `fgetc` and the cast value of `EOF` actually mean that an `EOF` is found at the end of a file. The problem is that if the file contains an `0xFF` byte this is also seen as an `EOF`.

In summary, change the type of `c` to an `int`.

Comment: THanks user3710044 .After your suggestion its working .